# How to filter a nested SwiftyJSON array

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have a `SwiftyJSON` array that is nested several levels and I need to filter the array based on a value in the lowest level.  Below is an example of an array.  I need to filter it on `Active == true`.  What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

```
var colors = JSON([
"Apple" : [
        "Yellow" : [
            "Active" : true,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ],
        "Red" : [
            "Active" : false,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ]
],
"Banana" : [
        "Blue" : [
            "Active" : false,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ],
        "Green" : [
            "Active" : true,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ]
]
])
```

Desired output:

```
"Apple" : [
        "Yellow" : [
            "Active" : true,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ]
],
"Banana" : [
        "Green" : [
            "Active" : true,
            "Working" : true,
            "Value" : 0
        ]
]
```

Comment: The *array* is a dictionary.

Comment: @MikeDeluca Check my answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
var filteredArray = [JSON]()

for item in colors {
    for subItem in item.1 {
        if subItem.1["Active"].boolValue {
           filteredArray.append(JSON([item.0:JSON([subItem.0:subItem.1])]))
        }
    }
}

print(filteredArray)
```

**Output is the array of Dictionaries of filtered sub dictionaries with Active true:**

```
[{
  "Apple" : {
    "Yellow" : {
      "Working" : true,
      "Value" : 0,
      "Active" : true
    }
  }
}, {
  "Banana" : {
    "Green" : {
      "Working" : true,
      "Value" : 0,
      "Active" : true
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a loop that will read all colors and within this loop to create one that will read the other items in the second array. Within the second is you check if the item is valid or not and save it in another array

```
let activeItems = []

for item in colors {
   for i in item as NSDictionary {
      if i.objectForKey("Active") == true {
         activeItems.addObject(i)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the array is JSON, giving error `cannot convert value of type (String, JSON) to type NSDictionary`

Comment: It is **not** an array.

Comment: @MikeDeluca No need to convert it to `NSDictionary`, it can be solved by simple `[JSON]` array of `SwiftyJSON`. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
        var result = [String:[String:JSON]]()
        for (key, json) in colors.dictionaryValue {
            let filtered = json.dictionaryValue.filter{$0.1["Active"].boolValue}
            guard filtered.count > 0 else { continue }

            var subDic = [String:JSON]()
            filtered.forEach{subDic[$0.0] = $0.1}
            result[key] = subDic
        }
        print(result)
```